# Turbolinks external javascript (here: ACE editor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ace-editor, turbolinks

I am trying to implement an ACE editor in a page which uses turbolinks. However, the editor only works when I directly call that page, or when I reload the page. Navigating to it won't trigger every necessary step to make the editor work.

Current integration:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.01/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.01/mode-html.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.01/mode-css.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function initialize_editor() {
    var editor = ace.edit("html-editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
    editor.setValue($('#template_html').val());

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
      $('#template_html').val(editor.getValue());
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(initialize_editor);
  $(document).on('page:load', initialize_editor);
</script>
```

This throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ace/ace' of undefined.` After leaving the page, the js seems to be stuck on the page, and on every navigation load, I get an  `Uncaught ReferenceError: ace is not defined`.

What's the proper way to include ACE editor (or other external libraries) here? Loading them via sprockets won't work, and when copying them into `vendor/javascripts/` and requiring them in the sprockets manifest, I had serious trouble getting it to run properly.

Any enlightenment about turbolinks and a proper way?

Comment: Turbolinks will reload your page content only when navigating by url, that means javascript will not get loaded/reloaded, try this gem [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), it may  solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by fetching the required js files and putting them into the vendor/javascript path. The initial problem with special chars for spaces and tabs (also reported here by others) could be solved by storing the files explicitly as utf8 with BOM.

Comment: I'm having problems with Ace and Turbolinks.  I don't want to put it into my asset pipeline because the files are large and I'm only using the editor on an admin interface.  Forcing all the users of the app to download the editor doesn't seem fair.